# Perform Download via download button in Python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am somehow new in the region of getting data from a website.

I have, e.g. a website http://www.ariva.de/adidas-aktie/historische_kurse and there is a donwload button hidden as shown in the picture below in red:

[image]

The main question is how can I download that in python? I tried some stuff found on the web (e.g. like beautiful soup, scraperwiki etc.) but somehow failed. 
The data download link is structured as the following:

```
> Kurse als CSV-Datei       </h3> <div class="clearfloat"></div> </div>
> <form action="/quote/historic/historic.csv" method="get"
> name="histcsv"> <input type="hidden" name="secu" value="291" /> <input
> type="hidden" name="boerse_id" value="6" /> <input type="hidden"
> name="clean_split"  value="1" /> <input type="hidden"
> name="clean_payout" value="1" /> <input type="hidden"
> name="clean_bezug"  value="1" /> <input type="hidden" name="currency" 
> value="EUR" /> <ul style="margin:5px;"> <li> <label
> for="minTime">von:</label> <input id="minTime" name="min_time"
> value="8.2.2016" style="width:71px" /> </li> <li> <label
> for="maxTime">bis:</label> <input id="maxTime" name="max_time"
> value="8.2.2017" style="width:71px" /> </li> <li> <label
> for="trenner">Trennzeichen:</label> <input id="trenner" name="trenner"
> value=";" style="width:25px" /> </li> <li> <input class="submitButton"
> name="go" value="Download" type="submit" /> </li> </ul> </form> </div>
> </div> <div class="clearfloat"></div> </div> </div> </div> <div
> id="foot" class="noprint"> <div class="adControllerAd evtAdShow 
> noprint abstand adHide" id="iqadtile16"> </div> <div id="footer"> <div
> class="footer abstand"> <a
> href="/adidas-aktie/historische_kurse?boerse_id=6&currency=EUR&clean_split=1&clean_payout=1&clean_bezug=1&min_time=2014-09-01&max_time=2017-02-07/wkn_A1EWWW_historic.csv"
> class="anker"> <img src="/forum/i/up.gif" alt="" width="9"
> height="9">Zum Seitenanfang</a> <a
> href="/fehlermeldung/index.m?ag=291&amp;referrer=&amp;ssl=0&amp;url=%2Fadidas-aktie%2Fhistorische_kurse%3Fboerse_id%3D6%26currency%3DEUR%26clean_split%3D1%26clean_payout%3D1%26clean_bezug%3D1%26min_time%3D2014-09-01%26max_time%3D2017-02-07%2Fwkn_A1EWWW_historic.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv?secu=291&boerse_id=6&clean_split=1&clean_payout=0&clean_bezug=1&min_time=8.2.2016&max_time=8.2.2017&trenner=%3B&go=Download'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('a.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

you can monitor the network use chrome dev tools, and when you click the download, the browser use `GET` method sending message to server and you can mimic it use `requests`
[image]

**how to find the parameters in the url:**
[image]

you can parse the page and get get the parameter you need, then build the download url and pass it to pandas.

**Use pandas read from link:**

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv?secu=291&boerse_id=6&clean_split=1&clean_payout=0&clean_bezug=1&min_time=8.2.2016&max_time=8.2.2017&trenner=%3B&go=Download')
```

**How to get the parameter:**

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'http://www.ariva.de/adidas-aktie/historische_kurse'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
payload = {field['name']:field['value'] for field in soup.select('form[name="histcsv"] input')}
csv = requests.post('http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv', data=payload)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to read things automatically out, like secu=291&boerse_id=6 instead doing it manual? Furthermore, can I write the csv file directly into a pandas dataframe? Somehow also the get API in the developer tool from chrome spits me different link out.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am still struggeling how to construct and easy scraper to read automatically the security ID

Comment: perfect thanks a lot! that is what i was looking for. Much appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest you to use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) where you can execute javascript without any extra effort. You can also use [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) for headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response for the download via this GET API,

> http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv?secu=291&boerse_id=6&clean_split=1&clean_payout=0&clean_bezug=1&min_time=8.2.2016&max_time=8.2.2017&trenner=%3B&go=Download

Here the `min_time` and `max_time` are the two date stamp which you will need to provide, and `trenner` is the separator, you can reciece the response and then write it to a file.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv?secu=291&boerse_id=6&clean_split=1&clean_payout=0&clean_bezug=1&min_time=8.2.2016&max_time=8.2.2017&trenner=%3B&go=Download')

file = open('download.csv','w+')
file.write(response.text)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am using the same comment as above: Is it possible to read things automatically out, like secu=291&boerse_id=6 instead doing it manual? Furthermore, can I write the csv file directly into a pandas dataframe? Somehow also the get API in the developer tool from chrome spits me different link out.